# Problems creating Uberjar in Clojure

Tags: clojure, leiningen, uberjar

I am using Clojure's `java-time` library, which is wrapper of `java.time` [1].

My program works when I invoke `lein run` or when I call the functions through the *repl*.  On the other hand when I try to do `lein uberjar` I get the following error with the classes involved:

```
$ lein uberjar
Compiling foo.cli
Compiling foo.core
Compiling foo.holidays
nil
Syntax error (ClassCastException) compiling at (/tmp/form-init8528909580728167374.clj:1:73).
class java_time.graph.Types cannot be cast to class java_time.graph.Types (java_time.graph.Types is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java_time.graph.Types is in unnamed module of loader clojure.lang.DynamicClassLoader @141c66db)

Full report at:
/tmp/clojure-6795557396101417445.edn
Compilation failed: Subprocess failed
```

I have isolated which expression causes this problem and it happens to be:

```
(java-time/minus  (java-time/local-date) (java-time/period 2 :days))
```

I am not sure why it is failing and the error is quite cryptic.  My bet is that the compiler gets confused casting some classes when generating the *uberjar* but it surprises me that the *repl* works fine.  Is it related to the `:aot` used for the *uberjar* creation?

This is a snippet of the `project.clj` file concerning that:

```
(defproject foo
  ...
  :main ^:skip-aot foo.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all
                       :jvm-opts ["-Dclojure.compiler.direct-linking=true"]}})
```

[1] https://github.com/dm3/clojure.java-time

Comment: I also wanted to add that there is not much information in the `.edn` created by the compiler that is not in the error message...

Comment: The error message says java_time.graph.Types, loaded by "app", is not compatible with java_time.graph.Types, loaded by clojure.lang.DynamicClassLoader... Are you doing something fancy with classloaders?

Comment: Nothing at all!

The only thing done in this project which is not purely Clojure is reaching to the `org.apache.poi` library to write excel files.  And that works fine!  I am only having this issues with the `java.time` wrapper `java-time`, with the `plus` and `minus` functions...

Comment: I have exactly the same symptoms with `(some-> 1614703906000 instant)`  (but not with  `(-> 1614703906000 instant)` and again it only happens with the direct-linking flag. It seems like the same problem, but I don't get your problem with `minus`. curiouser and curiouser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you have something wrong in your environment.  A sample program works fine for me:

```clj
    (ns demo.core
      (:use tupelo.core)
      (:require [java-time :as jt])
      (:gen-class))
    
    (defn -main [& args]
      (print-versions)
      (let [result (java-time/minus
                     (java-time/local-date)
                     (java-time/period 2 :days))]
        (println :result result)))
```

with result:

```sh
    ~/expr/demo > lein clean ; lein run
    
    --------------------------------------
       Clojure 1.10.2-alpha1    Java 15
    --------------------------------------
    :result #object[java.time.LocalDate 0x61a309fe 2020-10-05]
    
    
    ~/expr/demo > lein clean ; lein uberjar 
    Compiling demo.core
    Created /home/alan/expr/demo/target/uberjar/demo-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    Created /home/alan/expr/demo/target/uberjar/demo-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

For completeness, here is the `project.clj`:

```
(defproject demo "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url  "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [
                 [clojure.java-time "0.3.2"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure "1.10.2-alpha1"]
                 [prismatic/schema "1.1.12"]
                 [tupelo "20.08.27"]
                 ]
  :plugins [
            [com.jakemccrary/lein-test-refresh "0.24.1"]
            [lein-ancient "0.6.15"]
            [lein-codox "0.10.7"]
            ]

  :profiles {:dev     {:dependencies []}
             :uberjar {:aot :all}}

  :global-vars {*warn-on-reflection* false}
  :main ^:skip-aot demo.core

  :source-paths ["src/clj"]
  :java-source-paths ["src/java"]
  :test-paths ["test/clj"]
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :compile-path "%s/class-files"
  :clean-targets [:target-path]

  :jvm-opts ["-Xms500m" "-Xmx4g"]
  )
```

Comment: Well, as you stated the problem is in my environment.  The `"-Dclojure.compiler.direct-linking=true"` was blocking it from compiling.  Although now I am even more intrigued why it was causing this issue...

Comment: We use `clojure.java-time` at work and build uberjars with `-Dclojure.compiler.direct-linking=true` and have no problems. Perhaps you just need to run `lein clean` before `lein uberjar`?

Comment: Sadly this did not work either.

I have build uberjars too with `java-time`.  It worked as long as there is no `jt/plus` or `jt/minus` involved.  As soon as I used those functions the compiler was throwing this error.

It happened to me and also to a coworker working on the same codebase.